# For loops in Learn Python the hardway

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x

Sorry if this seems dumb to you but I'm having problems with LPTH's exercise 33

http://www.learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex33.html

Zed asks us to: re-write that exercise to use for-loops and range instead.  and Do you need the incrementor in the middle anymore? What happens if you do not get rid of it?

I did this:

```
numbers = []


def NumbersLoop(x):
    """
   This function will loop as long as x is less than the limit,
   at the same time it will print the numbers list
   """

    limit = int(input('Limit: '))
    increment = int(input('Increment: '))

    for i in (x, limit):
        print('At the top x is : {}'.format(x))
        numbers.append(x)

        x += increment
        print('Numbers now: ', numbers)
        print('At the bottom x is {}'.format(x))

NumbersLoop(1)

print('The numbers: ')

for num in numbers:
    print(num)
```

But I don't understand why it only loops until 
3. Also is it possible to get rid of the incrementor in the middle? I see no way to do it...

Comment: `for i in (x,limit):` should be `for i in range(x,limit,increment):`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to state the basic problem, and provide the *relevant* part of your code here. Posting it on pastebin makes your question meaningless if the site is down or the link is moved, and it makes it not searchable here. Questions here should stand on their own without any external data; the link can be provided as an additional reference like "Here's my code ... If you want to see all of it in context, it's at this pastebin link". Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few things wrong with that code, firstly:

```
for i in (x, limit):
```

You are missing the `range` call, and `x` is actually the start point, it is not changed by the range call.

Next:

```
print('At the top x is : {}'.format(x))
numbers.append(x)

x += increment
```

`x` is not affected by the `range` call, or the loop. The thing you want to be using is `i`, which is the number that the range is currently at.

Also, the `range` function takes the following arguments:

```
range(start, stop, increment)
```

You also don't need an to increment `x`, try the following with various arguments:

```
start = 0
stop = 10
inc = 2
for i in range(start, stop, inc):
    print(i)
```

If you ever have any problem in python, the first thing you should do is go to the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range) You will almost always find the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in (x, limit):
```

This means "run the loop twice: once with `i = x`, and once with `i = limit`".

Look at the assignment specification again. It says:

> re-write that exercise to use for-loops and `range` instead.

`range` is a function. You are not currently using it anywhere. You should be using it here.

`range` conceptually creates a range of numbers. This means that you can then loop `for i in` those numbers. For details, you should read [the documentation for that function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

> is it possible to get rid of the incrementor in the middle? I see no way to do it...

Get the `range` call working first, and then **try it**.

Answer (score 1):

This one was a good learning experiment; it causes the student to stretch for the answer while keeping it in reach. After extra credit step 5, this is where I ended up:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# FUNCTIONS
def genNos(noMin, noMax, noIncrement):
    """Returns numbers 0 through i in an array"""
    numbers = []
    for myNum in range(noMin, noMax, noIncrement):
        # print "At the top noMin is %d" % noMin
        numbers.append(myNum)
        # print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        # print "At the bottom noMin is %d" % noMin
    return numbers


# MAIN PROGRAM
print "The numbers: "
myVal = genNos(7, 21, 2)
print "%r" % myVal

for num in myVal:
    print num
```

Extra Credit:

Convert this while-loop to a function that you can call:

1. Function: genNos
2. Replace 6 in the test (i < 6) with a variable.
3. NOTE: initializing i outside of the function no longer works; move 'i = 0' to function.

Now use this function to rewrite the script to try different numbers:

1. Replace numbers with variables
2. Pass ranges to the function arguments.
3. NOTE: This works as long as the min is less than the max and the max is greater than/equal to noMin+(2*noIncrement).

Add another variable to the function arguments that you can pass in that lets you change the + 1 on line 8 so you can change how much it increments by

1. ADD: `noIncrement` (number by which you increment the count) to function arguments, pass a third value to the function.

Rewrite the script again to use this function to see what effect that has.

1. I did this to test everything above; it works to this point.

Now, write it to use for-loops and range instead. Do you need the incrementor in the middle anymore? What happens if you do not get rid of it?

1. OK, use for with range(); the [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function will take all of our arguments - no problem.

NOTES:
I never use 'i' or 'x' to represent variables in a loop, except for maybe unit testing; you can't do a search/replace in vim unless you use unique names; EG: :%s/myNo/MyVal/g; but this would be true of any program's search and replace.

Also, it seems like a `for-loop` is of greater cost to the compiler than a `while-loop`. In the context of causing a student to reach, this is a good experiment. I wouldn't use in real program however. Long-live the while loop!

Answer (score 1):

```
# get the input from the user for i
i = int(input("i>"))
# create an empty list and fill it later
numbers = []
# get input from user for the variable to use in while
num = int(input("num>"))

# Get the user input for increment number in while loop
incrementer = int(input("incrementer>"))
# Create a function and use while loop

def yourfunction(i):
    while i < num:
        # if user input for "i" is less than the user input for "num"
        print(f"at the top of i is {i}")
        # once i is printed, Add i to the list
        numbers.append(i)
        #once i is added to the list, print the list
        print("numbers now", numbers)
        # Then increment i by 1
        i += incrementer
        #once incremented, print i and repeat
        print(f"At the bottom of i is {i}")
# Call the function
yourfunction(i)
# print the newly created listsa
print(f"the new list is {numbers}")

for num in numbers:
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I would like to add something, because I just finished this problem.

What the OP might have been thinking(had he used range) is something like this:

```
numbers = []


def NumbersLoop(x):
    limit = int(input('Limit: '))
    increment = int(input('Increment: '))

    for i in range(x, limit):
        numbers.append(i) #The i would be the newly incremented x on next iteration. != True

        x += increment
```

**This code does not work properly.**

The reason is that while you may be expecting the newly incremented `x+= increment` to change the start point of the range on the next iteration, thus making `i` jump up by the incremented amount it **does not** .

The `x` that the range function uses is basically set in stone from when you first call it, so even if you changed the value to

```
x = 50
```

The next number that `i` takes on will be the next step towards the limit range based on the original x.

Maybe this will save the next person some time. 
You  use `range(start, end, increment)` .

Answer (score 0):

I'm 6 years late but also going through the LPTHW exercises. Here is what I put, simply just using a for-loop and range instead of a while-loop:

```
numbers = []

for i in range(0,6):
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)
    print "Numbers now: ", numbers
    print "At the bottom i is ", i + 1

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```